# How to connect the old descriptor with the new descriptor?

Tags: c, unix, fcntl, dup

Consider i have opened the file as `hell.txt` with the `open()` function.

```
  fd=open("hell.txt",O_RDONLY);
```

then, consider it will return the descriptor as `4`. and `hi.txt` already occupy the descriptor `3`, so i want to connect the `hell.txt`  file with `3` without using `dup2` or `fcntl()` function.

is it possible to change without using that two functions?

Comment: What is the context? What do you want to do with  file descriptor `3` afterwards? The simplest way to connect hell.txt to `3` is to close hi.txt and open hell.txt for the second time (assuming standard file descriptors 0-2 are open)

Comment: is dup3() allowed :^)

Answer (score 0):

because file descriptrs are usually occupied lowest number first this usually works:

```
close(3);
fd=open("hell.txt",O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: *"without using dup2 or fcntl() function."* -- I assume it also includes `dup()`